# Charset in content type of ajax post request different in browsers

Tags: ajax, character-encoding, content-type

I am currently experiencing a strange problem. When making an ajax post request I am setting the content type to the following:

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-1"
```

However, in chrome and firefox, when the call is made, the request header has a content type of:

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
```

Whereas in IE the content type is what I have set in the ajax call.

I have set the following meta tag in the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Can anyone shed some light on why IE would set the content type to ISO-8859-1 while Chrome and Firefox set it to UTF-8? Thanks!